# Section of javascript not running on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written a piece of Javascript in which one menu button is used to change both the appearance of the page and the href's of the menu itself.  I tried to create two "layers" of this (aka, have it change again when clicked again), but for some reason, only the first change is successfully called.  None of the second chunk of Javascript seems to be running at all when #black-button is pressed, neither the color changes nor the href changes, despite the fact that the nearly identical code above it works just fine.  Why is this chunk of script not running on command?

HTML:

```
<a id="advice-button-link" href="ln-advice.html" target="ln-content">
<div class="button" id="advice-button"></div>
</a>

<a id="poem-button-link" href="ln-poems.html" target="ln-content">
<div class="button" id="poem-button"></div>
</a>

<a id="pastel-button-link" href="pastel-phrases.html" target="ln-content">
<div class="button" id="pastel-button">deeper</div>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#pastel-button").click(function () {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor="#4444bb"
        $("#advice-button").attr("id","pastel-button-1");
        $("#advice-button-link").attr("id","pastel-button-1-link");
        $("#poem-button").attr("id","pastel-button-2");
        $("#poem-button-link").attr("id","pastel-button-2-link");
        $("#pastel-button").attr("id","black-button");
        $("#pastel-button-link").attr("id","black-button-link");
        $("#pastel-button-1-link").attr("href","pastel-phrases.html");
        $("#pastel-button-2-link").attr("href","pastel-phrases.html");
        $("#black-button").addClass('black-button-class');
});

$("#black-button").click(function () {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor="black"
        $("#pastel-button-1").attr("id","black-button-1");
        $("#pastel-button-1-link").attr("id","black-button-1-link");
        $("#pastel-button-2").attr("id","black-button-2");
        $("#pastel-button-2-link").attr("id","black-button-2-link");
        $("#black-button-1-link").attr("href","black-phrases.html");
        $("#black-button-2-link").attr("href","black-phrases.html");
        $("#black-button-link").attr("href","black-phrases.html");
});
```

EDIT:  To get rid of changing ID's, I came up with a new method which uses generic ID's for each button and just adds/removes classes to change appearance, and changes the href's based on what class the "Switcher button" (formerly pastel-button, black-button) has.  Still not working, I suppose because of the same reason (it doesn't originally have that class when the script is loaded.)  Is this still a step in the right direction?

```
$("#switcher-button").click(function () {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor="#4444bb";
        $("#content-button-1-link").attr("href","pastel-phrases.html");
        $("#content-button-2-link").attr("href","pastel-phrases.html");
        $("#content-button-1").addClass('pastel-1');
        $("#content-button-1").removeClass('original-button-1');
        $("#content-button-2").addClass('pastel-2');
        $("#content-button-2").removeClass('original-button-2');
        $(this).addClass('black-switcher');
        $(this).removeClass('original-switcher-button');
});

$(".black-switcher").click(function () {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
        $("#content-button-1-link").attr("href","black-phrases.html");
        $("#content-button-2-link").attr("href","black-phrases.html");
        $("#switcher-button-link").attr("href","black-phrases.html");
});
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you should never have to change the ID of an element, and certainly not on all of them ?

Comment: @adeneo Why not?  I'm changing almost all of the properties of said element, and I can't think of any other way to change its properties (i.e. have different CSS apply to it) more than once without changing its ID each time.

Answer (score 3):

`$("#black-button")` doesn't exist at the time your code runs.

You change an element ID to match it but that is *after* you have tried to add the event listener.

Changing element ID's is just a bad idea and is already causing you problems. Events get bound to elements, not to their ID or class

When you change the id of `pastel-button` to `black-button` that won't remove the event listener that you originally created for the element referenced originally by `pastel-button`

You could make this all work by using ***event delegation*** but I would suggest that is only going to mask a bad practice of switching ID's in the first place

**EDIT: A possible simplification approach**

Give the main links a common class and an extra data attribute that can be used to switch the class on the body

```
<a class="link-button" 
  id="advice-button-link" 
  href="ln-advice.html" 
  target="ln-content" 
  data-body-class="advice"><!-- used to switch class on body -->
    <div class="button" id="advice-button"></div>
</a>
```

Use that class to create one event handler. Within that handler change class on body and on active button:

```
$('.link-button').click(function(){
   var $link = $(this).addClass('active');
   $('.link-button.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
   $('body').removeAttr('class').addClass($link.data('body-class'));
});
```

Now with these body classes write css rules that do whatever is needed in the UI based on using body class as leading selector

Comment: I suppose that makes sense.  But what are my other alternatives that don't involve changing an ID?  Would changing its class be better practice?

Comment: toggling a class is far more common yes. Just realize that if you addd an event listener to a class...changing it;s class won't remove the original listener

Comment: So I'd run into the same problem right?  Meaning I have to completely change the way I'm doing this?  What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: The whole thing looks grossly over complicated in the first place. I'm not relly sure why you even need to change all those properties at all. Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish ... but it could likely be all scaled into one simple click handler that toggles and active class and works for all those links

Comment: Okay, that still doesn't really answer the question... What other less "grossly complicated" way is there to change the appearance and hrefs of a menu?

Comment: why do the href's need to change? that part i don't understand. As for display changes ...`addClass()` and `removeClass()` is likely all you need. Remember that `this` inside an event handler is element acted upon

Comment: added a simplification process that should help

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand this simplification process.  I edited the question to show a new way of doing it without changing ID's, although it still doesn't work (I assume for the same reason)

Comment: need to learn to use browser console to check errors...new code has syntax issues and can see it even in syntax highlighting. Console will tell you where you have syntax problems

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot.  Well, with that fixed, it sort of works, but skips right over "paste model" to "black mode".  I think I'm still having trouble coding to account for the fact that the script is processed all at once on pageload instead of changing things chronologically as we humans do.  I still can't figure out a way to add/remove classes one by one without triggering the second block of JS immediately, if you understand what I mean

Comment: all the style switching can be done using css `body.black-class{background:black} body.black-class .link-button.active { color:white}`

Comment: walk through the very simple logic of my approach in the js code. It's easy to interpret what is happening

Comment: As far as I can tell, that still only works for one color/href change.  There is no one "active" state, there are multiple different states the site can be in.